# Unable to integrate google sign in?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I have been trying to integrate google sign-in into my android application, but every time it gives a false result.
I have included the json configuration file as well checked the gradle files also.
Please help, I am stuck.
Here is my code

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        int statusCode = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        Log.d(statusCode+"oo", "joij");
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    Log.d(result+"hello", "hii me prateek");
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText("done");
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText("not done");
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: did u debug line by line??? whats the value of ```GoogleSignInResult result```

Comment: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@891c850

Comment: rakesh kashyap, it's of this format.

Comment: I didnt mean to check the value this way... you need to see each and every variable inside the ```GoogleSignInResult ``` class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just forgot to request for scope and idToken, see below.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Comment: whats the server_client_id?

Comment: 1.go to developer console https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=

2.select your project & Go to Credentials
3.Click on "Create Credntials"
4.Choose "OAuth client ID" option.
5.Fill the Details & you will get your server_client_id

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem correct to me, imo it's in the google dev interface, did you create API KEY, OAuth client Id etc ?

Comment: I did create the API key, but I am not sure about OAuth client Id.